# Upgraded to HTTPS and getting error from gtmetrix, unable to connect to the server

Tags: webserver, http, https

I just upgraded the settings in my server to use HTTPS and generate a free Let's Encrypt - Free SSL/TLS Certificates, I can access my website using the web browser (Chrome - Windows), however, when I try to test it using Pagespeed Insights (GTMetrix) I'm getting this error

```
Analysis Error
An error occurred fetching the page: HTTPS error: certificate verify failed
There may be a connectivity issue between your server and the GTmetrix test server. Try testing from another test location or try again later.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just missing CA Bundle (Contains Root And Intermediate Certificates)
In Direct admin go to  `SSL Certificates under Advanced Features Section`

[image: SSL Certificates Direct Admin]

on the bottom of the page click on `paste a CA Root Certificate`

[image: CA Root Certificate]

paste `CA Bundle` on the box and check `Use a CA Cert.`

[image]

then click save.